# iptables matching pattern followed by 4 random values followed by another pattern

Tags: linux, security, iptables, udp, packets

I'm trying to create a iptables rule that matches the following pattern in this UDP packet:

```
0x0000:  0000 030a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800  ................
0x0010:  4500 0027 5d30 0000 6c11 232a 5164 585d  E..']0..l.#*QdX]
0x0020:  c0a8 6402 fe25 1e61 0013 b382 5341 4d50  ..d..%.a....SAMP
0x0030:  c063 ba71 e2ea 63                        .c.q..c
```

The pattern is `|53414d50c063ba71|` followed by a random hex, in this case `|e2ea|`, followed by `|63|`.

The rule has to assure that there are 4 digits after the `|53414d50c063ba71|`, and that after those 4 random digits, there is a `|63|`.

Right now I have this, but I don't know how to modify it accordingly:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 7777 -m string --algo kmp \
    --hex-string '|53414d50c063ba71????63|' -j DROP
```

???? -> How??

Please help me.

Comment: I have seen it's possible to do this with http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-u32.current.html, but I don't know how to use it. Another option is to check the first part, just until before the 4 random digits (I know how to do it), and then match the LAST 2 digits with another rule. How to do that?

Comment: @A.B It's always the last position, in my UDP packet example, it's "63", it's always that last position, do you know how to do that with the example packet I've provided?

Comment: I made an answer but you never gave any feedback. So, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the offset is fixed, it's possible to use the [*u32*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#u32) match to do this kind of test. If the payload is at the end of the packet, that means the packet must be of constant size too for *u32* to be of any use.

Why? That's because *u32* can only add unsigned numbers, so it's not possible to match "last 11 bytes" expressed as "at position (packet size - 11)" with *u32* because there's a substraction (or an addition of a negative number).

So for this specific example with a payload size of 0x37 (55), as asked in comment, here's the *u32* match expression to use (packet being UDP will already have been validated by the udp match before):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 7777 -m u32 --u32 "0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0x34=0x53414d50&&0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0x38=0xc063ba71&&0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0x3b&0xff=0x63" -j DROP
```

Iterative explanations (of course, understanding [u32's manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#u32) and examples is needed):

`0x0 >> 0x16 & 0x3c` : adjusted [Internet Header Length (IHL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) <=> start of UDP header
`0x0 >> 0x16 & 0x3c @ 8` : 4 bytes at start of [UDP data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure)
`0x0 >> 0x16 & 0x3c @ 0x34` : 4 bytes at position (0x34-8) = 0x2c of UDP data
`0x0 >> 0x16 & 0x3c @ 0x34 = 0x53414d50` : 4 bytes at position 0x2c == `0x53414d50`
`&&` : logical *and*
`0x0 >> 0x16 & 0x3c @ 0x38 = 0xc063ba71` : 4 bytes at position 0x30 == `0xc063ba71`
`0x0 >> 0x16 & 0x3c @ 0x3b` : 4 bytes at position (0x3b-8) = 0x33 of UDP data
`0x0 >> 0x16 & 0x3c @ 0x3b && 0x000000ff` : content of last byte of the 4 bytes starting at position 0x33, meaning single byte at (here last) position 0x36
`0x0 >> 0x16 & 0x3c @ 0x3b && 0x000000ff = 0x63` : byte at position 0x36 == `0x63`